# Parse CSV-like file in PHP

Tags: php, csv, parsing

I have a file with the text like this in it and I want to modify it.

```
54.724498;25.340568;1262758;21;;14:51:42;A>B;1&54.70562;25.31099;1263367;21;;14:51:39;B>A;1&54.71681;25.305468;1262617;21;;14:51:33;A>B;1&54.68858;25.279688;1277721;20;;14:51:22;A>B;
```

I want it to be shown as this

```
54.724498 - 25.340568 - 1262758 - 21 - 14:51:42 - A>B - 1
54.70562 - 25.31099 - 1263367 - 21 - 14:51:39 - B>A - 1
```

So everytime it finds "&" sign, it jumps to another line. And it would be great if every string is added to different array, because I will later make a table. So it should be like this
54.724498 - array a, 25.340568 - array b, 1262758 - array c and so on...
My code for now is this:

```
<?php

$data = "54.724498;25.340568;1262758;21;;14:51:42;A>B;1&54.70562;25.31099;1263367;21;;14:51:39;B>A;1&54.71681;25.305468;1262617;21;;14:51:33;A>B;1&54.68858;25.279688;1277721;20;;14:51:22;A>B;");
//var_dump($data);

$parts = explode(';', $data);

$array = array();

foreach($parts as $part) {
    array_push($array,$part);
}

print_r($array);

?>
```

Comment: What is the current output or result of your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to transfer the data to a table then a good approach could be to `explode()` the string by `&` then `explode()` each element by `;` using `array_map()`,

```
$data = "54.724498;25.340568;1262758;21;;14:51:42;A>B;1&54.70562;25.31099;1263367;21;;14:51:39;B>A;1&54.71681;25.305468;1262617;21;;14:51:33;A>B;1&54.68858;25.279688;1277721;20;;14:51:22;A>B;";

$array = explode('&', $data);
$array = array_map(function($value){
    return explode(';', $value);
}, $array);

print_r($array);
```

You will now have a multidimensional array of data ready to be transfered to a table,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 54.724498
            [1] => 25.340568
            [2] => 1262758
            [3] => 21
            [4] => 
            [5] => 14:51:42
            [6] => A>B
            [7] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (

   ... etc...
```

Here's a live example - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9b4f0896b3fdda3da41797e9392d825bb044118

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$re = '/(.*)&(.*)/s';
$str = '54.724498;25.340568;1262758;21;;14:51:42;A>B;1&54.70562;25.31099;1263367;21;;14:51:39;B>A;1&54.71681;25.305468;1262617;21;;14:51:33;A>B;1&54.68858;25.279688;1277721;20;;14:51:22;A>B;';

preg_match_all($re, str_replace(';', ' - ', $str), $matches);

// Print the entire match result
echo '<pre>';print_r($matches);
```